# How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Firefox with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I need to create simple autotest using FirefoxDriver with Maven.

excerpt from pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
```

test case:

```
@BeforeTest
public void StartBrowser_NavURL() {
    capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capability.setCapability("platform", Platform.ANY);
    capability.setCapability("binary", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");


    driver = new FirefoxDriver(capability);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@AfterTest
public void CloseBrowser() {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void testToCompareDoubles() {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

And after running test executing command

```
mvn -test
```

I receive the following exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: egistering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager

`Mozilla Firefox version: 49.0.1` (it should be compatible with Selenium Webdriver). "hosts" file is empty. Windows firewall is disabled.

Do you have any ideas, how could I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like incompatibility issue between `Selenium2` and `Mozilla Firefox version: 49.0.1`.

Actually [`Mozilla` has launched executable `geckodriver` to support latest `firefox >= v47`](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) just like other driver executable with selenium.

[You need to download latest geckodriver executable first](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), extract downloaded zip file into your system at any location and set this executable path with executable itself into `System` properly with variable `webdriver.gecko.driver`.

[Now run selenium script to launch `Mozilla Firefox` using `marionette`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) as below :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver.exe");

//Now you can Initialize marionette driver to launch firefox
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(capabilities); //for selenium 3 use new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

**Note** :- If `Mozilla Firefox` installed at default location into your system, no need to provide explicitly binary path into selenium script, selenium would itself find it from default location.